# Can't finish my app onbackpressed

Tags: android

MainActivity starts GameActivity and from there user goes to the ScoreActivity.

I have override onBackPressed() for ScoreActivity and with an intent I go back to my MainActivity. From there if I press back again it goes to GameActivity instead of just finishing my app which is my goal.

I have tried overriding onBackPressed for MainActivity to call finish() but that doesnt works.

Any ideas of how I will achieve such a behavior ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your intent add a flag to clear other activities on your stack

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass Clear Activity Flags inside intent while going back to MainActivity from ScoreActivity.

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`